# W-NOMINATE method in R: Error Data contains values other than x or y or z

Tags: r

I realize that I may ask this question to a void because `wnominate` package is not of a wide use, but...

I have data on evaluation of state policies. I would like to know the potential choice polarization using [W-NOMINATE Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOMINATE_(scaling_method)). I have prepared my data according to the `wnominate` package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wnominate/vignettes/wnominate.pdf) (p. 9, 11). But when I try to apply the method to my data, I receive a very strange error:

```
Error in wnominate(rc_samp, polarity = c(2, 7)) :
  Data contains values other than 1 or 6 or 9.
```

And I do not understand what I am asked about. Can anybody clarify, what I am doing wrong? It will be a miracle if someone can help me with this package.

Data and code:

```
respNames <- samp$id
codeData <- matrix(samp$code, length(samp$code), 1)
colnames(codeData) <- "code"
samp <- samp[, -c(1,2)]

rc_samp <- rollcall(samp, yea = c(5,6,7), nay = c(1,2,3), missing = 4,
               notInLegis = 88, legis.names = respNames, legis.data = codeData, desc = "Ideological polarization")

samp_result <- wnominate(rc_samp, polarity = c(7,7))


structure(list(id = structure(1:100, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", 
"71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", 
"82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", 
"93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", 
"103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", 
"112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", 
"121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", 
"130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", 
"139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", 
"148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", 
"157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", 
"166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", 
"175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", 
"184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", 
"193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", 
"202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "210", 
"211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", 
"220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", 
"229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", "236", "237", 
"238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", "245", "246", 
"247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", "254", "255", 
"256", "257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", "263", "264", 
"265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", "272", "273", 
"274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", "281", "282", 
"283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", "290", "291", 
"292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", "299", "300", 
"301", "302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "307", "308", "309", 
"310", "311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "316", "317", "318", 
"319", "320", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", "326", "327", 
"328", "329", "330", "331", "332", "333", "334", "335", "336", 
"337", "338", "339", "340", "341", "342", "343", "344", "345", 
"346", "347", "348"), class = "factor"), code = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("control", "treatment_1", "treatment_2"
), class = "factor"), ideol_samesexmarriage = c(2, 7, 1, 2, 1, 
7, 6, 1, 88, 1, 6, 6, 4, 1, 6, 1, 1, 88, 1, 88, 7, 6, 4, 6, 6, 
6, 5, 7, 6, 3, 7, 4, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 7, 3, 6, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 88, 1, 7, 4, 7, 5, 5, 3, 7, 4, 7, 7, 88, 7, 7, 
7, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 1, 7, 7, 88, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 1, 7, 5, 
7, 7, 7, 1, 7, 5, 6, 5, 5, 7, 4, 7, 88, 2), ideol_flattaxes = c(5, 
7, 1, 2, 2, 1, 6, 6, 2, 1, 6, 2, 4, 5, 1, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 1, 88, 7, 5, 4, 1, 4, 
1, 5, 3, 4, 4, 7, 2, 2, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 6, 1, 
4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 1, 5, 7, 1, 7, 1, 6, 7, 3, 6, 2, 
2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 4, 5, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2), ideol_progrtaxes = c(2, 
1, 7, 5, 88, 5, 1, 1, 7, 7, 2, 6, 6, 1, 5, 5, 1, 6, 6, 5, 6, 
5, 6, 7, 4, 7, 5, 6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 5, 4, 3, 88, 6, 1, 4, 4, 1, 
4, 5, 2, 7, 5, 7, 1, 7, 7, 7, 2, 4, 7, 4, 7, 5, 6, 3, 7, 5, 1, 
7, 4, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 5, 1, 2, 5, 7, 3, 2, 7, 2, 7, 2, 1, 5, 1, 
7, 88, 3, 7, 7, 7, 3, 7, 5, 2, 7, 3, 7, 5, 5, 1, 6), ideol_democracy = c(4, 
7, 7, 3, 4, 7, 5, 1, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 7, 5, 6, 6, 88, 1, 6, 7, 
5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 2, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 3, 6, 4, 6, 7, 
2, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 2, 5, 7, 
4, 6, 7, 6, 4, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 1, 6, 6, 88, 5, 6, 5, 4, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 7, 3, 7, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 7, 4, 4, 1, 7), ideol_dictatorship = c(5, 
4, 5, 3, 1, 1, 5, 7, 2, 88, 6, 2, 7, 5, 2, 6, 3, 5, 7, 1, 1, 
7, 2, 6, 1, 7, 1, 5, 7, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 3, 7, 1, 
6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 
4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 7, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 
7, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 6, 2, 1, 5, 6, 1, 1), ideol_goveconomy = c(2, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 7, 1, 2, 4, 
1, 6, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 88, 3, 2, 1, 
4, 1, 3, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 7, 5, 
2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 6, 2, 4, 3, 3), ideol_govpaternalism = c(3, 
4, 5, 4, 88, 3, 5, 1, 6, 7, 7, 5, 4, 88, 5, 4, 3, 6, 1, 5, 6, 
2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6, 2, 7, 6, 7, 5, 5, 4, 88, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 
7, 3, 3, 7, 2, 7, 5, 7, 5, 3, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 2, 88, 5, 
6, 7, 4, 6, 6, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 2, 88, 7, 5, 6, 5, 2, 5, 4, 4, 
5, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5, 88, 6), ideol_govfreeimmigration = c(3, 
4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 6, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 6, 5, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 
2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 88, 6, 
2, 1, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 7, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 
2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2, 2, 88, 2), ideol_govimmigration = c(5, 
6, 7, 6, 88, 5, 1, 7, 4, 88, 6, 5, 7, 88, 6, 7, 7, 88, 7, 88, 
4, 88, 7, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 88, 3, 4, 6, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 6, 6, 
88, 5, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7, 88, 
7, 4, 7, 4, 6, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 6, 5, 88, 1, 7, 7, 4, 4, 6, 7, 
6, 6, 5, 7, 88, 3, 3, 3, 2, 6, 6, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5, 4, 88, 1, 6), 
    ideol_commongoals = c(3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 6, 2, 3, 
    4, 6, 2, 1, 2, 2, 7, 4, 4, 2, 2, 88, 1, 6, 1, 6, 2, 1, 7, 
    6, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
    7, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 88, 88, 1, 3, 5, 88, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 
    3, 4, 88, 2, 4, 88, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 7, 3, 4, 4, 1, 
    1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3), ideol_privatefreedom = c(5, 
    88, 7, 5, 7, 4, 3, 3, 5, 1, 6, 5, 4, 2, 5, 7, 6, 7, 1, 3, 
    3, 5, 5, 88, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 7, 2, 2, 7, 5, 5, 88, 6, 7, 3, 
    4, 1, 7, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 4, 3, 88, 
    7, 6, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 7, 7, 3, 88, 6, 6, 88, 7, 3, 5, 
    2, 4, 7, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 
    5, 3, 88, 3), ideol_goveconomy_lib = c(5, 2, 4, 2, 6, 3, 
    1, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 6, 2, 7, 1, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 
    2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 88, 4, 3, 5, 5, 6, 1, 3, 
    2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 88, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 88, 5, 5, 1, 
    4, 6, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 6, 5, 4, 1, 7, 5, 1, 1, 2, 6, 3, 7, 
    1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted with the package creator and we came to the (though unilateral) conclusion that `WNOMINATE` method is applicable to the data with big number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Rollcall votes should be coded as either 1, 6, or 9.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).